# Have I reached some limit of a scipy calculation?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

Something is interfering with half of the calculation I am performing. The begining and end values are correct, but I get nonsense in the middle. I assume I am reaching some limit, can someone advise me? Thanks in advance!

Also, I receive this error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 236
warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
improvement from the last ten iterations.
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.optimize


arr1 = [  0.00213078,  0.0021531,   0.00218033,  0.00220424,  0.00222176,  0.00223399,
          0.00224478,  0.00225169,  0.00225646,  0.00225647,  0.00223867,  0.0022049,
          0.0021622,   0.00210876,  0.0020441,   0.00197175,  0.00189047,  0.00180251,
          0.00171502,  0.00162689,  0.00154452,  0.00146999,  0.00140442,  0.00135468,
          0.00134417,  0.001344,    0.00135512,  0.0014063,   0.00147986,  0.00156551,
          0.00165978,  0.00175712,  0.00185474,  0.00195226,  0.00204777,  0.00214,
          0.00222465,  0.00230082,  0.00236566,  0.00241465,  0.00244476, 0.0024569,
          0.00245195,  0.00243146,  0.00239689,  0.00235529,  0.00231654 , 0.00227621,
          0.00223002,  0.00217016]

arr2 = [  0.00096938,  0.0009819,   0.00099678,  0.00101073,  0.00102057,  0.00103018,
          0.0010413,   0.00105218,  0.00106356,  0.00106902,  0.00106544,  0.00105494,
          0.00103801,  0.00101643,  0.00098957,  0.00095677,  0.00091982,  0.00087941,
          0.00083751,  0.00079612,  0.00075754,  0.00072171,  0.00069068,  0.00066782,
          0.00066305,  0.00066328,  0.00066785,  0.00069156,  0.00072594,  0.00076707,
          0.00081058,  0.00085682,  0.00090321,  0.00094914,  0.00099353,  0.00103551,
          0.00107464,  0.00110769,  0.00113554,  0.00115547,  0.00116511,  0.00116531,
          0.00115689,  0.00114069,  0.00111821, 0.00109352,  0.00106985,  0.0010461,
          0.00102085,  0.00098881]

def equation(x, R1, R2):
    y = np.exp(math.pi*.082*R1/-x)+np.exp(math.pi*.082*R2/-x) - 1
    return y

def solver(R1, R2):
    return (scipy.optimize.fsolve(equation, 0.05, args=(R1,R2,)))

test_array = np.vectorize(solver)(arr1, arr2)
print test_array
```

Comment: "I get nonsense in the middle."  Then it would help if you eliminated the big loop over `arr1` and `arr2`, and find one example of values for `R1` and `R2` that cause the problem.  For those values, plot `equation(x, R1, R2)` to see if there is anything unusual about the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `brenth()`:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.optimize


arr1 = [  0.00213078,  0.0021531,   0.00218033,  0.00220424,  0.00222176,  0.00223399,
          0.00224478,  0.00225169,  0.00225646,  0.00225647,  0.00223867,  0.0022049,
          0.0021622,   0.00210876,  0.0020441,   0.00197175,  0.00189047,  0.00180251,
          0.00171502,  0.00162689,  0.00154452,  0.00146999,  0.00140442,  0.00135468,
          0.00134417,  0.001344,    0.00135512,  0.0014063,   0.00147986,  0.00156551,
          0.00165978,  0.00175712,  0.00185474,  0.00195226,  0.00204777,  0.00214,
          0.00222465,  0.00230082,  0.00236566,  0.00241465,  0.00244476, 0.0024569,
          0.00245195,  0.00243146,  0.00239689,  0.00235529,  0.00231654 , 0.00227621,
          0.00223002,  0.00217016]

arr2 = [  0.00096938,  0.0009819,   0.00099678,  0.00101073,  0.00102057,  0.00103018,
          0.0010413,   0.00105218,  0.00106356,  0.00106902,  0.00106544,  0.00105494,
          0.00103801,  0.00101643,  0.00098957,  0.00095677,  0.00091982,  0.00087941,
          0.00083751,  0.00079612,  0.00075754,  0.00072171,  0.00069068,  0.00066782,
          0.00066305,  0.00066328,  0.00066785,  0.00069156,  0.00072594,  0.00076707,
          0.00081058,  0.00085682,  0.00090321,  0.00094914,  0.00099353,  0.00103551,
          0.00107464,  0.00110769,  0.00113554,  0.00115547,  0.00116511,  0.00116531,
          0.00115689,  0.00114069,  0.00111821, 0.00109352,  0.00106985,  0.0010461,
          0.00102085,  0.00098881]

def equation(x, R1, R2):
    y = np.exp(math.pi*.082*R1/-x)+np.exp(math.pi*.082*R2/-x) - 1
    return y

def solver(R1, R2):
    return scipy.optimize.brenth(equation, 1e-30, 100, args=(R1, R2), xtol=1e-30)

for idx, (t1, t2) in enumerate(zip(arr1, arr2)):
    r = solver(t1, t2)
    print idx, r, equation(r, t1, t2)
```